# change localhost hostname in nginx

Tags: nginx

I have multiple local sites and I want to configure nginx to have a different host of each website.

In /var/www I have 2 sites: site1 and site2

Then in /etc/nginx/sites-available/ I created 2 different configurations server for each one. I have the files site1 and site2 which content is like:

```
server {
        listen 80;

        root /var/www/site1;
        index index.html index.htm;

        server_name localhost;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }
}
```

and

```
server {
            listen 7777;

            root /var/www/site2;
            index index.html index.htm;

            server_name localhost;

            location / {
                    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
            }
    }
```

I access to them with `http://localhost:80` for site1 and `http://localhost:7777` for site2. That works perfectly. I also could add the hostname in /etc/hosts like this:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost site1 site2
```

and I could access them with `http://site1:80` and `http://site2:7777`. But I have to access always to the port number. I want to access them by `http://site1` and `http://site2`.

Is there a solution to do that ?

Comment: I found the solution by changing the server_name to site1 and site2 and then putting the same port 80.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You already figured it out but let me explain a bit why it's working.

The first site `site1` should have worked just fine, because the default `http` port is 80, and that's what `site1` was listening to, so `http://site1.com` would have worked just fine.

The second config file for `site2` was listening to port `7777` so doing a normal `http://site2.com` would have not worked, actually it probably would have picked your default website and served that instead, because nginx isn't trying to match the `server_name` with the one in the config because the port doesn't match.

You should create all your websites on port 80 and nginx will do the matching by it self and know which site to server, unless it's an `https` website then you'd use port `443` instead, that's the default ssl port

Answer (score -1):

To set `/etc/hosts` for windows 10.

Go to `c:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts` directory and open the file with a text editor and then add this line `127.0.0.1 localhost site1 site2`.

Then open any browser and hit `site1/`. Make sure it is `http://`, not `https://`.